# fast-forward during git rebase - why?

Tags: git

I have the history like this:

```
o (master)
| \
|  o (feature)
|  |
|  o
| /
o
```

I'm doing `git rebase feature master` and get the following:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded new to master.
```

I didn't know fast forward was possible with `rebase`. How does it work?

What if I wanted the commits on `feature` branch starting from `master` branch tip, how would I achieve this?

PS. I'm just trying to understand why this behaviour, not how to go about it. I've just tested another situation with additional commit on master after the merge commit, and still got `fast-forward` rebase.

Comment: What is it that you expect here?  `master` *has* those commits so there's nothing to rebase...  Do you want empty commits that just maintain the metadata?

Comment: Since the topmost commit here is only a merge commit, you might just want to reset your master onto feature: `git checkout master && git reset feature`. Amirite?

Answer (score 0):

Use the three commit form with --onto:

```
git rebase common feature --onto master~1
```

Note that you cannot rebase on top of the merged branch, as that would've required to first undo the merge, which would change history.

Comment: What is `common` in this case?  The common ancestor?  If so, then this will be a no-op since `feature` is already based off `common`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: it's not a noop since we're reading to `master~1` not `master`.

Comment: Did you try it?  `Current branch feature is up to date`.  All it could do is re-create the two commits in `feature` on top of `common`, which is already their base.  Unless `common` is not the common ancestor, it's not clear since that didn't exist in the OP's question.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: I did try it but my master before the merge do have some other commits, I see now that the OP doesn't have any commits on the other parent of the merge. Now I'm at a loss of what the OP is trying to do with his rebase

Comment: @LieRyan, I'm not trying to do anything, I'm just experimenting and trying to understand what happens and why... sort of a process of learning through experiments)